# Retrieving last set of input values from a char pointer

Tags: c, string, algorithm, pointers

I have a few set of values in a single char* variable such as this:

```
char* a1 = "1234 4567 789";
char* a2 = "123 445";
```

They are separated by white space.

I am trying to retrieve the last set of value such as 789 and 445 from the char*, but I am not too sure how to do this.

I am currently doing this:

```
trimmed[strchr(trimmed, ' ') - trimmed] = '\0';
```

This only nets me the second set of value which doesn't work if there are more than 2 inputs.

Is there a good way to extract the final set of value irregardless whether if there is 1 or 3 inputs?

Comment: The answer you accepted is wrong. I updated my answer with code working with `strchr()`. Nice question BTW, +1.

Comment: You should use `strrchr` which does exactly what you want instead of `strtok` or `strchr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a corresponding function manually. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * extract( const char *s, size_t n )
{
    if ( n == 0 ) return NULL;

    while ( n != 0 && isspace( ( unsigned char )s[n-1] ) ) --n;
    while ( n != 0 && isdigit( ( unsigned char )s[n-1] ) ) --n;

    return ( char * )( isdigit( ( unsigned char )s[n] ) ? &s[n] : NULL );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    char *s1 = "1234 4567 789";
    char *s2 = "123 445";

    char *p1 = extract( s1, strlen( s1 ) );

    while ( p1 )
    {
        printf( "%d ", atoi( p1 ) );
        p1 = extract( s1, p1 - s1 );
    }        
    printf( "\n" );

    p1 = extract( s2, strlen( s2 ) );

    while ( p1 )
    {
        printf( "%d ", atoi( p1 ) );
        p1 = extract( s2, p1 - s2 );
    }        
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

The program output is

```
789 4567 1234 
445 123
```

Take into account that you may not apply standard function `strtok` to string literals as it is suggested in some answers here.:)

Comment: I agree with the last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtok`, which will split your string based on a pattern (white space in this case)

```
char *a1 = "1234 4567 789";
char *ptr;
char *tmp = strtok(a1, " ");
while(tmp != NULL)
{
    ptr = tmp;
    tmp = strtok(NULL, " ");
}

//ptr holds now the last value
```

Comment: @Bocky It is a wrong answer. You may not apply strtok to string literals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strrchr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strchr) which returns a pointer to the last occurrence.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
  char *s = "1234 4567 789";
  char *s2 = strrchr(s, ' ');
  if (s2 != NULL)
    printf("%s\n", s2 + 1);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [strchr()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/), you can track down the last occurrence of the whitespace, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
  char *str = "1234 4567 789";
  char *pch;
  int last_idx = 0;
  pch = strchr(str, ' ');
  while (pch != NULL) {
    last_idx = pch-str+1;
    pch = strchr(pch+1,' ');
  }
  printf("%s\n", str + last_idx);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 789

---

Alternatively, you can use [strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) (but not with string literals) like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void) {
  char str[] = "1234 4567 789";
  char *pch, *last_pch = str;
  pch = strtok (str, " ");
  while (pch != NULL) {
    last_pch = pch;
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
  printf ("%s\n", last_pch);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

> 789

Here we actually remember the last `pch` that was actually a substring token and we do not care about the number of tokens.

Comment: The solution with strchr is wrong. Consider a situation when the string contains only one number.

Comment: The program has undefined behaviour. Function strchr will return NULL and the statement with printf after the loop will use uninitialized variable last_idx.

Comment: Oh damn, @VladfromMoscow *of course* you are right. I updated my answer with an initial value for the index which will take care of this situation! Thank you (I am going to upvote another answer of yours, since I already did for this one here as a gift).